# Mqtt data package size when simulating image data mining from a robotics device

Tags: data-visualization, mqtt, data-mining, robots.txt

Visual data mining is

> Is the process of interaction and analytical reasoning with one or more visual representations of abstract data. The process may lead to the visual discovery of robust patterns in these data or provide some guidance for the application of other data mining and analytics techniques. It facilitates analysts in obtaining deeper understanding of the underlying structures in a data set. The process relies on the tight interconnectedness of tasks, selection of visual representations, the corresponding set of interactive manipulations, and respective analytical techniques. Discovered patterns form the information and knowledge utilized in decision making. ([Link](https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007%2F978-0-387-39940-9_1121))

When we try to simulate these feed of visual data by a robotic IOT device to a application what is the maximum **payload + Base64 converted image string** data-size we could pass through mqtt massaging protocol?

Comment: This can be a silly question in general. but if you try to read about "visual data mining" you will see image data mining, data visualization etc. are always referring to visual data mining even though those are completely different from it.

Answer (score 2):

Visual data mining is the use of interaction and visualization for data mining (e.g. clustering).

It has nothing to do with image data mining, which is the automatic detection of patterns in images, and the unsupervised sibling of image recognition.

"visual data mining robots" does not make any sense.

Comment: thank you for your quick response. can you give a definition for "image data mining".